# Join for has_many_through in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations, has-many-through, has-many

I have 3 models as following.

```
class Order
 belongs_to :item
 belongs_to :category
end

class Item
 has_many :orders
 belongs_to :category
end

class Category
 has_many :items
 has_many :orders, through: :items
end
```

I want to join the tables like  `Order.joins(:item).joins(:category)`, but it's not working.

Desired SQL is

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` 
INNER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`id` = `orders`.`item_id` 
INNER JOIN `categories` ON `items`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
```

I hope your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused because Order and Item both belongs_to Category and Category already has_many Orders with that setup, the `:through` option is unnecesary.

For your desired output I guess you want to do a nested join (order > item > category) instead of multiple joins (order > item+category)

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-multiple-associations

> 12.1.3.1 Joining Nested Associations (Single Level)
>   Article.joins(comments: :guest)
>
> This produces:
>
> SELECT articles.* FROM articles
>     INNER JOIN comments ON comments.article_id = articles.id
>     INNER JOIN guests ON guests.comment_id = comments.id

So, you should do something like `Order.joins(item: :category)`

Comment: Thanks.
Order.joins(item: :category) is working well.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're looking for is

```
Order.joins(item: :category)
```

Check [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-multiple-associations) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to setup these associations is:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  # This references items.category_id
  has_one :category, through: :item
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item, through: :orders
  has_many :orders
end
```

You want to remove the `orders.category_id` column (if it exists) and use an indirect association through the items table to avoid duplication. The semantics of `belongs_to` and `has_one` can be confusing but `belongs_to` assumes that the foreign key is on *this model* (orders), while `has_one` places it on the *other models* table (items).

This will let you join/include/eager_load the association with:

```
irb(main):002:0> Order.joins(:category)
  Order Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."id" = "orders"."item_id" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "items"."category_id" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

And as you can see Rails will handle joining the join table (items) automatically.

If you want both associations to be loaded you can use a   hash or just list both:

```
Order.eager_load(item: :category) 
Order.eager_load(:item, :category)
```